# I have no clue how to use Datorama with Contacts Counts

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, cloud, datorama

Good morning,

So we use Discover Report for Account send Summary, deliverability, and contacts counts, my main problem is I can't get the information of CONTACTS COUNTS on Datorama, and I would like to get some help.

Also, will Discover reports disappear yes or yes? :/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discover reports will go away on April 1

Datorama does not have contact counts, you would simply use the [standard report](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_contacts_counts.htm&type=5) to get this information

> The Contact Count report contains information on the total number of contacts in an account, and it runs weekly. The report also shows the Month End Report that runs on the last day of the month.

Comment: Hello EazyE, thanks for your fast reply. I thought Discover Reports and the Reports were both the same kind of report. Does that mean even after day April 1, we will be able to use the Report with it's catalog?

Comment: standard reports != discover reports

Comment: Now I got it! Lol. Thanks a lot, EazyE!

Comment: @Unomia please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share how I've figured out how to populate subscribers count in Datorama. It's possible. Here's how:

1. Creating a Automation that Query the DataView _Subscriber and write the Totalnumber of subsribers and the data in a targeted Data Extension (Scheduled on a daily basis).
2. Create a Data Stream in Datorama using the Marketing Cloud Data Extension API Connector.
3. Map the Data from the Targeted Data Extension to a custom Datorama Data Stream.
4. Use the Aggregation method "LAST" on the Totalnumber of subscribers variable.
5. Use the "Incremental" (Adds the new data alongside the old data.) option for data updates.
6. Go into Workspace > CreateWidget and select the variable Totalnumber of subscribers as measurement and Day as dimension.